# Where is Remote Desktop Connection for Mac in Office 2011?

Tags: ms-office, remote-desktop

I've just installed Office for Mac 2001 (v14.3.3), on this page (http://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) it says "Remote Desktop Connection for Mac 2 is included with every edition of Office for Mac 2011." but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: If it's not in Additional Tools (use spotlight to search for it), you can [download it for free from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=microsoft%20remote%20desktop%20connection%20for%20mac&p=0&r=10&t=&s=Relevancy~Descending).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in my case it is right here

[image]

In your case it might be waiting for you in the "Downloads folder" to be installed.
If not get it from MS here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1350

Comment: Same for me as the above poster. The RDC app is written to the root of ~\Applications.

Comment: It looks like the 2 answers came at same time :). @Dave you are correct if it comes as part of the Office, but if it is downloaded as stand alone, it goes in the download folder first.